# Routing Django ORM Based on URL Parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have a scenario where we have 4 databases that are exact duplicates of each other in terms of structure and functionality. Each database represents a different division within our company.

We are using DRF to prove a REST API for these databases. My goal is to define the same Models/Serializers/Views and reuse them for every database. We then allow the developer to specify a "server" url parameter in their request. The app then selects the correct database based on that server parameter.

We already have multiple databases in our app and a `router.py` configured. I assume the best way to solve this problem is to add some logic in the `db_for_read` and `db_for_write` methods.

My question is that I am not familiar with these methods/class. How can I pass the server parameter from the Django view into this router so one of the routing methods can access it and select the corresponding database? Or is there another way to implement this that I am missing?

Comment: This seems backward to me. Why not just use different addresses to access different databases, such as `http://division1.company.org/employee/12345`, `http://division2.company.org/employee/54321`? This could then make it much easier to have e.g. different access controls on who can see what in the future. Exposing the database exposes the internal implementation of the system anyway, which is not how django was to designed to operate and makes your system more fragile to change in the future.